# Trying to identify a short story about an unexplained spaceship crash, whose solution is finally inspired by a Mark Twain quote

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A large spaceship (1000 or so passengers) at the end of its first flight botches a tail-down autopilot-controlled landing and kills everybody aboard.

Investigators are all mystified, but one, inspired by a quote from Mark Twain that I can't remember, figures out what happened.  I had thought it was in one of Lem's Pirx the Pilot collections, but it isn't.  Maybe it was in an anthology.  I read it decades ago but I don't remember exactly when.

I just ordered more of Stanislaw Lem's short stories.  Maybe I'll run into it.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE. When exactly did you read this?

Comment: Was that quote something like "a man cannot be pardoned for a crime which he has not committed"?

Comment: fez: Can't recall.  Decades ago.
YK: I wish I could remember

Comment: Even a range of years would help, anything to narrow down the scope

Comment: Decades ago.  I can't nail down the year.

Comment: Are you certain it is not a Pirx tale? In the story 'Ananke' the huge spaceship Ariel, the first of his kind, attempts a tail-down landing on its maiden voyage to Mars and crashes. The following investigation cannot uncover the causes of the crash. Pirx starts understanding what has happened, but has no proof. He then sends an E.A. Poe (not M. Twain) quote to the person whose decisions/work ultimately set in motion the events leading to the crash 'THOU ART THE MAN'.

Comment: @ErnstdeRidder that's gotta be it. Well done.

Comment: In re-reading "Ananke" the other day, I was wondering if I had just recalled it incorrectly after all these years.  The similarities to what I thought I remembered were certainly remarkable.  Maybe that IS the one!

Comment: giralua: So, do you remember any other details so we can look further? Or shall I turn 'Ananke' into an answer that you can accept?

Comment: Ernst: Now I must consider the possibility that I recalled some details quite incorrectly.  What I recalled was a large passenger vessel carrying about 1000, and a tail-down landing that slowly collapsed the whole ship.  And of course, Mark Twain.  False memories?  Let's wait a while and see if anyone comes up with anything closer.

Comment: There's a Mark Twain quote that may fit: "Necessity is the mother of taking chances." In Greek mythology, Ananke is the personification of fate or necessity and, in the Pirx tale, the ship was unable to take any chances. That sounds like the kind of connection an author would appreciate.

Answer (score 5):

Since the comment that names the story never made it into an answer, I leave this here with a bit of detail . As per the comments, this is the Pirx Story "Ananke", which ends with a quote not by Twain, but Edgar Allan Poe, "Thou Art the Man" (would make it also a duplicate of this: [Short story where a spaceship is too cautious during landing, wants to gather information, interprets situation as asteroid collision and crashes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/285860/short-story-where-a-spaceship-is-too-cautious-during-landing-wants-to-gather-in) which has an accepted answer).

At the end of the story Pirx deduces correctly who is responsible for the crash, a former superior of his who was retired from service due to OCD and sent to a facility where he "trained" navigational computers. Through his training methods he "imprints" his own neurosis onto the computer, who then in a difficult situation succumbs to decision paralyses and crashes the ship during landing on Mars.

Pirx is at a loss of what to do, because this is not a theory he can plausibly bring to the people leading the investigation; at the same time he needs to act fast, since another spaceship with a similar defect is on the way.

He remembers that his former superior is a fan of Edgar Allan Poe and sends him said quote, from a story in which the corpse of a man accuses its own murderer - a ruse in the Poe story (the corpse is spring loaded and points at the murderer as he opens the coffin), as well as obviously in the Lem story, and in both cases it brings the responsible persons to confess. Pirx former captain scribbles a note in which he assumes responsibility before he shoots himself, which is enough to have the other spaceship stopped before it also crashes.

That is the literal summary of the story - it is actually a story about aging (astronauts from a younger generation who die because they blindly trust the computer even as it runs them into the ground, Pirx' old captain who cannot accept being made obsolete, and Pirx himself on the border between the two).

At least in my German anthology this is bundled with another story ("Albatros") in which Pirx witnesses the loss of a passenger liner via radio while traveling on another spaceship, so those stories might have run together in the memory of the OP.